# ASP como crer una tabla

Tags: html, asp.net, asp

actualmente este es mi codigo ASP , pero no tengo idea de como podria crear una tabla ue divida el ID y Nombre de los autos

```
<%

if isArray(listaTipo) then
for i = lbound(listaTipo ,2) to ubound(listaTipo ,2)
    response.write ( "ID->"& listaTipo(0,i) &" + Nombre: "& listaTipo(1,i) 
 &"<br /><br />")
  next'i
 else
response.write ("<div class='alert' >")
response.write ("No existen registros de tipos de autos")
response.write ("</div>")
end if

%>
```

Actualmente mis datos se me ven asi .

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puedes crearla con el **response.write**

```
if isArray(listaTipo) then
     Response.Write("<table><tr><td>ID</td><td>Nombre</td></tr>")
     for i = lbound(listaTipo ,2) to ubound(listaTipo ,2)             
          response.write ("<tr><td>"& listaTipo(0,i) &"</td><td>"& listaTipo(1,i) &"</td></tr>")
     next
     Response.Write("</table>")
 else
     response.write ("<div class='alert' >")
     response.write ("No existen registros de tipos de autos")
     response.write ("</div>")
end if
```

Espero sea de ayuda

Comment: Me sirvió , Muchas gracias :D

Comment: De nada @Daniela